# Jackrabbit Indexing Config Whitelisting (Magnolia CMS 5.5.5 Fulltextsearch)

Tags: indexing, lucene, content-management-system, jackrabbit, magnolia

I want to do a whitelisting of what properties are indexed/searched and shown in excerpt with a Magnolia search.

I am changing the indexing_configuration.xml in my website workspace.
Removing the index and restarting magnolia did not change anything...

By now I have this in my indexing_configuration.xml (next to other stuff)
but these are the String properties I want to include in my ecxcerpt the rest should be excluded:

```
   <index-rule nodeType="nt:hierarchyNode">
      <property boost="10" useInExcerpt="true">introTitle</property>
      <property boost="1.0" useInExcerpt="true">introAbstract</property>
      <property boost="1.0" useInExcerpt="true">contentText</property>
      <property boost="1.0" useInExcerpt="true">subText</property>
      <property boost="10" useInExcerpt="true">title</property>
      <!-- exclude jcr:* and mgnl:* properties -->
      <property isRegexp="true" nodeScopeIndex="false" useInExcerpt="false">.*:.*</property>
   </index-rule>
   <index-rule nodeType="mgnl:contentNode">
      <property boost="5" nodeScopeIndex="false" useInExcerpt="true">introTitle</property>
      <property boost="2" nodeScopeIndex="false" useInExcerpt="true">introAbstract</property>
      <property boost="2" nodeScopeIndex="false" useInExcerpt="true">contentText</property>
      <property boost="2" nodeScopeIndex="false" useInExcerpt="true">subText</property>
      <property boost="5" nodeScopeIndex="false" useInExcerpt="true">title</property>
            <!-- exclude jcr:* and mgnl:* properties -->
       <property isRegexp="true" nodeScopeIndex="false" useInExcerpt="false">.*:.*</property>
   </index-rule>
```

How can i get this to work as intended? Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely cause is that Magnolia/JR is not seeing your new configuration. Did you change your repo configuration (`workspace.xml` in `website` workspace) to point it to new index configuration?

Default looks like:

    `<SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
      <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index" />
      <!-- SearchIndex will get the indexing configuration from the classpath, if not found in the workspace home -->
      <param name="indexingConfiguration" value="/info/magnolia/jackrabbit/indexing_configuration.xml"/>`

and you need to point it to your new file.

Also not sure why you are setting indexing based on `nt:hierarchyNode` or `mgnl:contentNode` rather then using more specific `mgnl:page`/`mgnl:component`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jan, but I still got a problem. Now i can exclude some properties from FullTextIndex by setting nodeScopeIndex="false" and useInExcerpt="false". The excerpt looks much cleaner. But now it shows "admin" and "superuser" in the excerpt (multiple times) which should be excluded with the line <property nodeScopeIndex="false" isRegexp="true" useInExcerpt="false" >.*:.*</property> .. What is the problem here?

Comment: I found it .. I needed index rules for: mgnl:page , mgnl:component AND mgnl:area...